# Debugging Mass Transit / Rabbit MQ

Tags: c#, debugging, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am testing messages and running into some odd behavior. The messages seem to be not published at random and I'm not sure why. (I am using MassTransit / Rabbit MQ.)

I enabled the tracing plugin and listening to all messages. When messages do get 'dropped' (not hitting the consumer), I do notice that they are not displayed in the logs.

Is there a way to see a reason when I call Publish() and it does not hit the consumer?

Client:

```
IBusControl bus = GetBusControl(); //call Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq
bus.Start();
bus.Publish<IMyContract>(messageObject);
bus.Stop();
```

Server:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IMyContract> context)
{
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question.  As your post stands right now, it will get downvotes from a [lack of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode).

Comment: `Publish` is an `async` method. Sometimes, your bus stops before the message is published. You need to await the async call.